Restricting powerbi unnecessary cookies while using powerbi-client-angular:2.0.0 library
Issue : We observed powerbi adds cookies that are non-necessary ex. ai_session, ai_user

Angular version : 11
powerbi-client-angular : 2.0.0
API from which the cookie is passed as request : https://powerbi-df.analysis-df.windows.net/undefined
API call generated by powerbi-client-angular lib
Expectations : We would like to disable/suppress these cookies.
Observations : We also identified this cookies are being added as request from web app which has powerbi-client-angular dependency
How can this be achieved in angular or using any other mechanism?
